# post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'uidb64' Reset password rest_auth

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

Now I work on reset password with rest_auth what ever the email be sent and URL be open like this but I add the values on it:
This is the page when I click on URL sent in email:
[image: This is the page when i click on url sent in email]

And after the fill the fields and make a post request I get this:
This is the error I get:
[image: This is the error i get]

And here is my URLs:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', include('rest_auth.urls')),
path('login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='account_login'),
path('registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
path('registration/', RegisterView.as_view(), name='account_signup'),
re_path(r'^account-confirm-email/', VerifyEmailView.as_view(),
     name='account_email_verification_sent'),
re_path(r'^account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$', VerifyEmailView.as_view(),
     name='account_confirm_email'),
re_path(r'^password/reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),
     name='password_reset_confirm')
]
```

And the view is but it's built in in rest_auth:

```
class PasswordResetConfirmView(GenericAPIView):
"""
Password reset e-mail link is confirmed, therefore
this resets the user's password.

Accepts the following POST parameters: token, uid,
    new_password1, new_password2
Returns the success/fail message.
"""
serializer_class = PasswordResetConfirmSerializer
permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

@sensitive_post_parameters_m
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(PasswordResetConfirmView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

def post(self, request):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
    return Response(
        {"detail": _("Password has been reset with the new password.")}
```

Comment: What are the values that you filled in the form ?

Comment: values:
https://imgur.com/a/1dHo2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your URLconf causes the post method to be called with two kwargs – uidb64 and token – but your post method does not accept any kwargs. To get rid of the error, just add the kwargs to the post method signature:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # ...
```